# Using Named parameters and Bundled properties with edmonds_karp_max_flow()

Tags: c++, templates, boost-graph, max-flow, edmonds-karp

I am trying to use *Named parameters* with *Bundled properties* in the `edmonds_karp_max_flow` algorithm of the Boost-graph library.

To show my problem, I took the existing [edmonds-karp example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/graph/example/edmonds-karp-eg.cpp) and turned the Internal properties into Bundled properties (I called my properties `edge_t` and `node_t`), and the Named parameters into Non-named parameters.

Here is the Non-named parameter version that compiles fine:

```c
// The "non-named parameters version" (works fine)
edmonds_karp_max_flow(g, s, t,capacity,residual_capacity,rev,col,pred);
```

Here is the Named parameters version that doesn't compile and triggers a lot of template errors:

```c
// The "named parameters version" (produces errors)
flow = edmonds_karp_max_flow(g, s, t,
            capacity_map(capacity)
            .residual_capacity_map(residual_capacity)
            .reverse_edge_map(rev)
            .color_map(col)
            .predecessor_map(pred));
```

The full `edmonds-karp-eg_modified.cpp` source:

```c
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/graph/edmonds_karp_max_flow.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/read_dimacs.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
using namespace boost;

typedef adjacency_list_traits<vecS,vecS,directedS> traits;
struct edge_t {
    double capacity;
    float cost;
    float residual_capacity;
    traits::edge_descriptor reversed_edge;
};
struct node_t {
    std::string name;
    boost::default_color_type color;
    traits::edge_descriptor predecessor;
};

typedef adjacency_list < listS, vecS, directedS, node_t, edge_t > Graph;
int main()
{
    Graph g;
    property_map < Graph, double edge_t::* >::type capacity = get(&edge_t::capacity, g);
    property_map < Graph, float edge_t::* >::type cost = get(&edge_t::cost, g);
    property_map < Graph, float edge_t::* >::type residual_capacity = get(&edge_t::residual_capacity, g);
    property_map < Graph, traits::edge_descriptor edge_t::* >::type rev = get(&edge_t::reversed_edge, g);

    property_map < Graph, std::string node_t::* >::type name = get(&node_t::name, g);
    property_map < Graph, boost::default_color_type node_t::* >::type col = get(&node_t::color, g);
    property_map < Graph, traits::edge_descriptor node_t::* >::type pred = get(&node_t::predecessor, g);

    traits::vertex_descriptor s, t;

    read_dimacs_max_flow(g, capacity, rev, s, t);

    long flow;
    // XXX The "non-named parameters version" (works fine)
    // flow = edmonds_karp_max_flow(g, s, t,capacity,residual_capacity,rev,col,pred);
    // XXX The "named parameters version" (produces errors)
    flow = edmonds_karp_max_flow(g, s, t,
            capacity_map(capacity)
            .residual_capacity_map(residual_capacity)
            .reverse_edge_map(rev)
            .color_map(col)
            .predecessor_map(pred));

    std::cout << "c  The total flow:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "s " << flow << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << "c flow values:" << std::endl;
    graph_traits < Graph >::vertex_iterator u_iter, u_end;
    graph_traits < Graph >::out_edge_iterator ei, e_end;
    for (boost::tie(u_iter, u_end) = vertices(g); u_iter != u_end; ++u_iter)
        for (boost::tie(ei, e_end) = out_edges(*u_iter, g); ei != e_end; ++ei)
            if (capacity[*ei] > 0)
                std::cout << "a " << *u_iter << " " << target(*ei, g) << " "
                << (capacity[*ei] - residual_capacity[*ei]) << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here are the errors returned : http://pastebin.com/Vra8ZWHG.

It works fine with non-named parameters... But not with the named parameters.

**Update:** Someone seems to have the exact same issue: svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/8791. He fixed it using `Boost 1.50` instead of `1.55`.

- Boost-graph version: 1.58.0
- Compiler: g++ 5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a Graph bug: named_function_params.hpp, line 326, has the arguments to get_param_type in reverse order.  Changing this makes it compile for me.

There don't appear to be any test cases for Edmonds-Karp with named parameters and clearly there need to be...

Comment: Excellent! This is the problem.

Comment: Btw, the bug has also been found in the [boost trac](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/8791).
And I also found out that `find_flow_cost()` had also some [errors](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11374)...

Comment: And here is the [pull request for that issue](https://github.com/boostorg/graph/pull/40) :) Thank you, @JeffTrull!